# javascript copy element to clipboard with all styles

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

I am trying to copy a div to the clipboard. The div has a few styles, including a **background**. I have made a script to copy the div to the clipboard, but I can't figure out how to do the background.

I have seen this done, but I can't remember how.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

This is as far as I got:

```js
function executeCopy(text) {
    var copyDiv = document.createElement('div');
    copyDiv.contentEditable = true;
    document.body.appendChild(copyDiv);
    copyDiv.innerHTML = text;
    copyDiv.unselectable = "off";
    copyDiv.focus();
    document.execCommand('SelectAll');
    document.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
    document.body.removeChild(copyDiv);
}
```

```css
#foo {
  background-color: red;
  font-family: cursive;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">Test</div>
<button onclick="executeCopy(document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML);">Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try the following fiddle. It works with every text style there is and it's interoperable with MS Word and Pages (I just tested it).

The code is pretty straightforward so I wouldn't really get into the depths of it, but feel free to drop me any questions should you feel like. :)

```
const copyWithStyle = ( element ) => {

    const doc = document;
    const text = doc.getElementById( element );
    let range;
    let selection;

    if( doc.body.createTextRange ) {

        range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElement( text );
        range.select();

    } else if ( window.getSelection ) {

        selection = window.getSelection();

        range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents( text );

        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange( range );

    }

    document.execCommand( 'copy' );
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    document.getElementById( 'clickMe' ).value = 'Copied to clipboard!';

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aypdg3kL/

From the example in JSFiddle

HTML

```
<div id="text" style="color:red">
    <i>Hello</i> world!
</div>
<input id="btn" onclick="CopyToClipboard('text')" type="button" value="Copy" />
```

JS

```
function CopyToClipboard(element) {

        var doc = document
        , text = doc.getElementById(element)
        , range, selection;
    
    if (doc.body.createTextRange)
    {
        range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } 
    
    else if (window.getSelection)
    {
        selection = window.getSelection();        
        range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
    document.execCommand('copy');
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    document.getElementById("btn").value="Copied";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting [@weirdpanda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48554118)'s excellent example to modern HTML APIs, you get the following: if you run the example and click the "Copy" button and paste into a spreadsheet program like Excel, you'll get the same beige-and-gray table (with "2.0" possibly unhelpfully rendered as "2" ).

And this will continue to work if you put this in an HTML file and serve it over plain HTTP—but caveat, for an accurate test, you must host it on a non-`localhost` HTTP URL because your browser will probably give `localhost` a secure context.

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = () => {
  const target = document.querySelector("table");
  copyElement(target);
};

function copyElement(target) {
  const range = document.createRange();

  range.setStart(target, 0);
  range.setEndAfter(target);
  window.getSelection()?.removeAllRanges();
  window.getSelection()?.addRange(range);

  document.execCommand("copy");
  
  window.getSelection()?.removeAllRanges();
};
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead {
  background-color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: beige;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button>Copy</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Type</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Murderbot</td><td>SecUnit</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ART</td><td>Research transport</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Amena</td><td>Human</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Tlacy</td><td>Augmented human</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2.0</td><td>Sentient virus</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```