# Not being able to copy URL to Clipboard without adding the protocol https

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new in working with ASP.NET and Javascript. Recently I came across this problem where I had to copy the URL on a javascript button action and paste on a new tab to visit the website. It does work locally but not on the live server. I found out that it was due to not adding 'https'. Is there any way where it can work without using 'https' like 'http' only?

```js
function CopyTextFunction() {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  params.get('ID')
  var copyText = "https://randomshop.net/OnlineShop/ShopProducts?ID=" + params.get('ID');
  console.log(copyText);
  navigator.clipboard
    .writeText(copyText)
    .then(() => {
      alert("successfully copied");
    })
    .catch(() => {
      alert("something went wrong");
    });
}
```

Comment: I shared a version that works with plain-HTTP and copies as `text/html` MIME type (with styles, etc., so good for pasting into apps expecting rich text like Excel, etc.) over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77489472/500207 which with the `document.execCommand` but using the `Range` API.

Answer (score 10):

As you correctly stated this is due to not using HTTPS. According to MDN [`Clipboard`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard) docs: *"This feature is available only in [secure contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts)"*.
**The best option would be to just use HTTPS.**

---

But since you asked for a workaround, here's a (hacky) working sample. It uses the [`Document.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)  command, which in the future will be deprecated in favor of [`ClipboardAPI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API).

```js
function unsecuredCopyToClipboard(text) {
  const textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textArea.value = text;
  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.focus();
  textArea.select();
  try {
    document.execCommand('copy');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Unable to copy to clipboard', err);
  }
  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}
```

You could then use `navigator.clipboard == undefined` to use the fallback method, otherwise use the normal `navigator.clipboard.writeText(...)` function where supported.

E.g, from your above code:

```js
const copyText = `https://randomshop.net/OnlineShop/ShopProducts?ID=${params.get('ID')}`;

if (navigator.clipboard) { // If normal copy method available, use it
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
} else { // Otherwise fallback to the above function
  unsecuredCopyToClipboard(copyText);
}
```

Comment: Great solution but little bit annoying scroll to the newly created element at the end of the document, to avoid that just use `textArea.focus({preventScroll:true});` instead of just `textArea.focus();`

Comment: Can this method be used to set the copied content's MIME type, i.e., `text/html`? Or is it limited to `text/plain`? I want to copy an HTML `<table>` for pasting into spreadsheet apps for example.