Copying is not successful: NotAllowedError: Failed to execute 'writeText' on 'Clipboard':
I'm trying to copy text from my Flutter web app, which is being used within an iframe, but I'm encountering a permission error. Is there any way to resolve this issue? I need to copy content from the Flutter app and store it in my clipboard. Without the iframe, it works fine. I have tried Clipboard.setData and html.window.navigator.clipboard?.writeText, but both methods result in the error: Copy is not successful: NotAllowedError: Failed to execute 'writeText' on 'Clipboard': The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53651

You need to use a secure context as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72237719/not-being-able-to-copy-url-to-clipboard-without-adding-the-protocol-https

my web app uses HTTPS .iframe app and parent app.
