# Is there a way to copy paste the contents of an HTML table into an Email Message?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, email, html-table

I'm working on a locally hosted website using HTML, CSS, JS, Flask and SQLite3.

I want to create a functionality where the user is able to share the contents of a table via Email and I've created a 'Share via Email' button for the same.

When I run the program, the body of the email simply contains - ${inventoryTable} and the content is not displayed.

I know the data isn't being retrieved correctly. How do I resolve this.

I don't think I can attach the entire HTML page as its confidential, but the specific line of code I'm talking about is below...

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=Inventory Table &body=Inventory table details:%0D%0A%0D%0A ${inventoryTable}" target="_blank">Share via Email</a>
```

This line is supposed to retrieve data from a table wiht ID = "inventoryTable."

This is what part of inventoryTable looks like -

```
<table id ="inventoryTable">
                <tr style="position: absolute; margin-top: -40px; z-index: 1;">
                    <th>Product ID</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Price(₹)/Unit</th>
                    <th>Quantity Available</th>
                    <th>Shelf Location</th>
                    <th>Accept Returns</th>
                    <th>Reorder Quantity</th>
                    <th>Edit Item</th>
                    <th>Delete Item</th>
                </tr>
                {% for item in data %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.price}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.quant_a}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.shelf}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.returns}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.quant_r}}</td>
                    <td>
```

I basically want the table headers and the rows to be copied into the email. I think I need to use JS for this but I'm not sure.

Help, please.

P.S. - I'm a 16yr old high-school kid doing this for a real-world client so could really use some help. (Also would really appreciate it if you could explain your solution a tad bit extra).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript copy element to clipboard with all styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554043/javascript-copy-element-to-clipboard-with-all-styles) - Just tested your code with the answer provided to that question and it copies the table just fine.

Comment: Do you have any sort of server-side?  c# mvc php python?  It's much easier to generate an email using one of those.

Comment: @icecub I would guess that OP is using the wrong terminology for "copy + paste into an email" (ctrl-c / ctrl-v...)  but rather they want to generate an email with the table already present `<a href='mailto:...`

Comment: @freedomn-m Yeah, that's what I was going for. Thanks for correcting me. Btw the server side is Flask (Python).

Comment: @icecub I guess I could try using the solution you gave for copying the table into the clipboard. Then maybe I could try and use some of the execCommand() methods in JS to access the clipboard and try pasting it (not sure if it's possible as I didn't research it in detail).

Comment: If you come across any other solutions please lemme know

Comment: @freedomn-m Ah, that makes sense. Well as per [RFC6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068): _"The "body" field value is intended to contain the content for the first text/plain body part of the message. The "body" pseudo header field is primarily intended for the generation of short text messages for automatic processing (such as "subscribe" messages for mailing lists), not for general MIME bodies."_, so no. Technically it's not possible to generate rich content purely client side.

Comment: That said, there is a workaround here: [mailto link with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-link-with-html-body/46699855#46699855)