# Copy Text converted using TTf fonts to clipboard

Tags: javascript, php, html, go, clipboard

I've extensively searched the depths of the internet, eager to seamlessly incorporate TTF font styling to user input. With a vast repository of over 12,000 TTF font files hosted on my website, the current functionality generates input text as PNG files. However, I'm now enthusiastic about enabling users to directly copy applied styled text using Ttf fonts. I'm open to exploring solutions in any programming language. Feel free to review my current implementation here: https://update.cutestfonts.com/. I'm flexible and capable of working with any programming language or solution.

I tried converting the ttf font to woff and then use to output the text, but when someone copies it doesn't pick the ttf font style. I tried manipulating the current code like imagettftext() but no success.

Comment: https://codepen.io/adnan-malik/pen/gOyGdQB

Comment: Not clear. Do you want to copy text or image to the clipboard?

Comment: I want to copy the converted text to chipboard

Comment: In first step i want to convert the input text from user using ttf font to new style and then copy that output text to clipboard keeping that style

Comment: There is no "conversion" here. You just apply a font style.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript copy element to clipboard with all styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554043/javascript-copy-element-to-clipboard-with-all-styles)

Comment: It didn't help, the style(font family/type is not getting copied with it

Comment: yeah I meant the conversion as applying font style and then copy the text with that style

Comment: You need to use `<div>`elements with `contenteditable` attribute otherwise styles get stripped. However, this wouldn't copy any fonts. See [example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/LYvzaBE).  If a font is not available you see a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not possible.**

Because the font is not applied to the text and is applied to the visible output for you. Therefore, the font will never be a part of your text and you will not be able to copy or share it as text.
**The solution for your case is to provide an image output** to the user and copy, share or save the generated image of the text with the font applied.

Of course, the **explanations provided are for file fonts** with specific formats. Otherwise, there are some limited characters that can be used to write the desired text with a certain style, which is not available in all languages and is not a suitable approach to use. The best approach is what was said, that is, using the method of creating an image for the user